# Collecting combobox variables

Tags: php, variables, combobox

I'm creating a form to read distinct entries from a database and populate them in a combo box, which all works great, unfortunately, I cant see how to send the variables correctly to the receiving page.

I know that because its a combo box ill need an array to store the variables in, but im not sure where I should put it in the code. The PHP code for the combo box is shown below.

```
<?php
  # parameters for connection to MySQL database
  $hostname="hostname";
  $database="database";
  $username="username";
  $password="password";
             // Connect to the database
  $dblink=mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password") or die ("Could not connect to the server");
  mysql_select_db("$database") or die ("that database could not be found");

           # check if link is successful – if not kill the script
           if (!$dblink) {die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
                   }   else   {
                   }

            // Create the form, post to the same file
// echo "<form method='post' action='combo.php'>";


echo "<form name='form' method="POST" action='index'>";



// Form a query to populate the combo-box
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM dbusers;";

// Successful query?
   if($result = mysql_query($query))  {

// If there are results returned, prepare combo-box
   if($success = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

// Start combo-box
   echo "<select name='item'>\n";


   echo "<option>-- Username --</option>\n";

// For each item in the results...
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

// Add a new option to the combo-box
   echo "<option value='$row[username]'>$row[username]</option>\n";

// End the combo-box
   echo "</select>\n";
}
// No results found in the database
   else { echo "No results found."; }
    }
// Error in the database
   else { echo "Failed to connect to database."; }
// Add a submit button to the form
   echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' /></form>";

?>
```

This all seems to work fine in looking up distinctive entries and populating them so far, but I cant do anything with the data.

For basic text fields I just gave the input a name and send it, then collect it on the receiving page, but that doest seem to work in the combobox.

That is the correct snippet and location to assign this combobox's data a variable so I can send it to a process page? I am looking for it to be able to store multiple data values for filtering so some sort of array for values will be needed but ive not got much experience with arrays of variables, most notably creating and retrieving!

Thanks

Comment: It's called an dropdownlist

Comment: for starters, since your using `method=POST` why dont you use `$_POST`

Comment: because until now i thought i needed a variable to retrieve using that. like $search=$_POST['username_search']; are dropdown boxes different and would still allow multiple selections?

Comment: @user3611960 use `<select multiple="multiple">` multiple attribute